# can media query changes based on main div width instead of window width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my Friends I have a problem.i have a project that has 3 buttons in it's header .these buttons change width of main div to my specific width has set in my Java script.i want something like media queries for example change my div color or hide or show something when div width changes. i know I can use Java script to define background color for every width but imagine that i have navbar that has sandwich menu button on mobile.this button can easily hide in an specific width that i have defined on my media queries;but what about hiding this button when my main div width decreases to mobile view width instead of changing browser width?
please excuse me for this long text.

```
<body>
    <header>
      <span role="button" class="header-collapse"
        ><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i
      ></span>
      <ul class="screens">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tablet-alt"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <main class="content">
      
    </main>

    <footer>
      <span>Coded by Mahdi Baghaei</span>
    </footer>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
*,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  min-height: 5vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e4e1fc;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.header-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #e4e1fc;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #2512cc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
.header-collapse:hover {
  background-color: #a49af6;
  color: white;
}

.header-set {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header-collapse-set {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotateZ(-180deg);
}

.screens {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.screens li a {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  color: #2512cc;
  align-items: center;
}
.screens li a:hover {
  background-color: #a49af6;
  color: white;
}
.screens li a i {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.content-mobile {
  width: 768px;
}

.content-tablet {
  width: 1200px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #e4e1fc;
  min-height: 5vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
footer span {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .content {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const headerCollapse = document.querySelector(".header-collapse");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");
const screenSwitch = document.querySelectorAll(".screens li");

headerCollapse.addEventListener("click", headerCollapseF);

function headerCollapseF() {
  header.classList.toggle("header-set");
  headerCollapse.classList.toggle("header-collapse-set");
}

screenSwitch[0].addEventListener("click", mobileView);
screenSwitch[1].addEventListener("click", tabletView);
screenSwitch[2].addEventListener("click", standardView);

function mobileView() {
  content.style.width = "768px";
  content.style.border = "1px solid black";
}
function tabletView() {
  content.style.width = "1200px";
  content.style.border = "1px solid black";
}
function standardView() {
  content.style.width = "100%";
  content.style.border = "1px solid white";
  
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

Comment: thank you for your response my dear friend. Is there another way for doing this?? because css container queries not yet supported by older version of browsers

Comment: @Mahdi For older browsers, you will have to write your own logic using JS & update the Layout based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using iframe html tag
thanks you all.